# Scrollable Frame without scrollbar (ie compatibility mode)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

i'm wondering if there's a possibility to apply scrolling on a <"frame"> in internet explorer in compatibility mode.

We've large app, that is only running on old ie(i just come to team week ago).
Let's say code is similiar to this.

```
 <frameset cols="140,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="*">
   <frame name="leftFrame" src="menu4.jsp" scrolling="no" noresize></frame>
   <frame name="mainFrame" src="StartPage.jsp"></frame>
 </frameset>
```

This would be obvious question, but ***i don't want to see scrollbar***. Does anyone got an idea how to solve it maybe?

Comment: `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: on what? on frame? :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px !important;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

Might help you out !

Comment: This has no effect beyond webkit powered browsers.